# I would like to get count of rows within 2 related Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models within my models.py as shown below:

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Student(models.Model):
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    dob = models.DateField()
    current_class = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would to display count of how many students are there in each class. For example, if we have 10 students in Class 1, 15 students in Class 2, 20 students in Class 3, 25 students in Class 4 and so on.

I would like to display something like, what's shown below:

Class 1 (10)
Class 2 (15)
Class 3 (20)
Class 4 (25)

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this? - `Student.objects.all().values('current_class').annotate(total_students=Count('current_class'))`

Comment: Thanks for responding @Charnel, I did try your solution, but getting the following error. ```'function' object has no attribute 'values'```

Comment: That's pretty weird. `all()` shout return queryset, but not function. Did you override model manager?

Comment: My bad @Charnel, I had missed parenthesis for all. But now I'm getting a different error. ```TypeError: 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment```

Comment: Can you show exact code you're trying to run?

Comment: I'm using it on a different table: Here Classroom is represented as State and Student is represented as Job. ```state_count = Job.objects.all().values('state').annotate(total_state_count=Count('state'))```  state is the equivalent field of current_class as present within the Student model for Job model.

Answer (score 1):

you can also work directly with the reverse relation from your Classroom Model.

```
for room in Classroom.objects.all():
   print(room.student_set.count())
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks @LetItBeAndre I'm able to get the count, but how do I display in the following format: Class 1 (10), Class 2 (20) and likewise.

Comment: Hey @Shahzan to print the format you need just write the print like this:
print(f'Class {room.pk} ({room.student_set.count()})')

Comment: Thanks again, @LetItBeAndre :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Count` and `annotation`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class_rooms = Classroom.objects.all().annotation(students_count=Count("student"))
```

and then:

```
for room in class_rooms:
    print(room.students_count)
```

Comment: Thank you both for suggesting the solution, I did try both the solutions, but none of them worked. getting the following error: ```AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'annotate'```